# Completion listener for multiple setvalues

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have lots of string values I upload to Firebase database. I want to add an oncomplete listener to ensure they are uploaded before the user continues. How could I add one listener instead of multiple?

This is the code I'm using for the oncomplete listener:

```
 reference.child(booking).child("Date").setValue(date, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
@Override
public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
    if (firebaseError != null) {
        System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
    }
}

 reference.child(booking).child("Time").setValue(time, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
@Override
public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
    if (firebaseError != null) {
        System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
    }
}
```

Comment: would i need to do a hashmap for all the values n do an oncomplete listener to the one hashed version? sorry ive not coded in a year n cant remember lol

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this by using a `Map`. So you need to put a Map the exact data that you want to add/update and at the end you'll use a single complete listener.

Comment: yeah i think i remebered just as you marked it as a duplicate haha cheers @AlexMamo